# Android roles and file permissions

Tags: android, permissions, chmod

I would like to understand something about Android's roles and, specifically, why if I execute this function of the class Context

```
openOutputFile(filename, MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE)
```

the created file has write permissions for each role (User, Group, Others), whilst has read permissions just for User and Group.
I think it is not an o.s. lock, because if I try to change permissions executing this code

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 666 FILE_PATH")
```

it sets read and write permissions for each role.

Is it normal? "Who are" people in Others' role?
Why the first instruction does not set read permission for "Others"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it normal?

Yes.

> "Who are" people in Others' role?

All apps on the device, other than yours.

> Why the first instruction does not set read permission for "Others"?

Because you did not ask it to. Use `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` to set read access bits.

Comment: Thanks!
But... then, who are people in group?

Comment: @user1507512: I am not aware that there are any UIDs are in your group other than your own, but I have not looked.

Answer (score 1):

"Android is a privilege-separated operating system, in which each application runs with a distinct system identity (**Linux user ID and group ID**). Parts of the system are also separated into distinct identities. Linux thereby isolates applications from each other and from the system."

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

Also, here are some research results:

http://elinux.org/Android_Security#Users_and_groups